# Erro ao executar buscar por data maior do que 1 ano função DATADIFF() e DATAADD()

Tags: sql, sql-server

Olá preciso realizar um select em uma base de dados onde a dataCompra seja maior do que um ano. Porém preciso usar uma clausula and no meu where e  quanto tento usar a função DATEDIFF() e DATEADD()  dessa maneira ela não retorna nada. Há alguma limitação nessas funções ou o meu select que está incorreto?

```
select tb_Pedido.idPedido, 
        numeroPedido,dataCompra 
   from tb_Pedido, tb_NotaFiscal
     where DATEDIFF(dd,dataCompra, getdate()) > 366 AND
       tb_Pedido.idPedido = tb_NotaFiscal.idPedido AND
       tb_NotaFiscal.ARMAZENADO =0;
```

Com dateadd()

```
select tb_Pedido.idPedido,numeroPedido,dataCompra  
  from tb_Pedido, tb_NotaFiscal
   where  
      tb_Pedido.dataCompra <= 
      DATEADD(yyyy,-1,getdate())
      AND tb_Pedido.idPedido = tb_NotaFiscal.idPedido AND
      tb_NotaFiscal.ARMAZENADO =0;
```

Porém quando uso somente o where sem a clausula and ele funciona, porém preciso do and para fazer uma verificação.

Comment: checou se os dados realmente atendem? o usos das funções está correto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A diferença entre os dois métodos é que no primeiro usa diferença em **dias**, e no segundo devolve uma data/hora **com menos um ano**.
 Em **anos bissextos** há uma diferença no critério efetivamente. 

Por outro lado GetDate() devolve também a hora.

```
select DateDiff(dd,'2017-09-28','2018-09-28')
```

365

```
Select DateAdd(yyyy,-1,getdate())
```

'2017-09-28 10:09:00'

Answer (score -2):

Acredito que usando Join seria mais prático

```
SELECT 
     PED.IDPEDIDO
    ,PED.NRPEDIDO
    ,PED.DATACOMPRA
FROM TB_PEDIDO      PED
JOIN TB_NOTAFISCAIS NF   ON (NF.IDPEDIDO = PED.IDPEDIDO)
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(DAY, PED.DATACOMPRA, GETDATE()) > 366
AND NF.ARMAZENADO = 0
```